# Customizing email subject with dynamic data in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

> **Not a duplicate of** [Display order total with and without VAT in Woocommerce's order email notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50766161/display-order-total-with-and-without-vat-in-woocommerces-order-email-notificati).

How can I customize the **subject** of the E-mail, *(not the body. I know how to edit the variables in the body, but the same variables don't work in the subject for some reason).*

So I am trying to change the **subject** of WooCommerce order email notifications.

The subject is customizable via WooCommerce -> Settings -> E-mails -> New Order -> Manage… and according to WooCommerce documentation, there are variables such as `{order_date}`, `{customer_name}`, etc... that can be use to get dynamic order data.

My problem is that I would like to show the "**order number**" and the "**order total**" in the subject:

- If I use the format: `Order {order_number} - {order_date} - {dollars_spent_order}`
- I should get: `Order # 123456 - July 6, 2018 - {dollars_spent_order}`

But it doesn't work. Using single or double curly-braces makes no difference.

How can I add the order total (including tax, shipping, etc) to the E-mail subject line?

I would like to get the following result:

> Order # 123456 - July 6, 2018 - $ 1,234.56

I Googled this, but didn't find any code snippets that show me how to do this.

There's also a "WooCommerce Follow-Ups" extension that adds more variables, but it's $ 99.00 and I don't need all those, just the order total. There's GOT to be a code snippet somewhere...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display order total with and without VAT in Woocommerce's order email notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50766161/display-order-total-with-and-without-vat-in-woocommerces-order-email-notificati)

Comment: @Mohammad Sorry but if you pay attention reading the title first and the body of the question, you will see that this question can NOT be a duplicate of the linked answer you suggest *(one of my answers)*.

Comment: **To the community:** Sorry but this question *has a clear statement and include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.* So please reopen it as the answer is something useful for the community.

Comment: I'd love to know the answer to this, too. It's not a duplicate, email body and subject line are different things.

Answer (score 3):

To customize for example the "New Order"email subject *(sent to the admin)*, you will use the following hooked function:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_subject_new_order', 'custom_email_subject', 20, 2 );
function custom_email_subject( $formated_subject, $order ){
    return sprintf( __('Order # %d - %s - %s', 'woocommerce'), 
        $order->get_id(), // Order ID
        $order->get_date_modified()->date_i18n('F j, Y'), // Formatted date modified
        wc_price($order->get_total()) // Order Total
    );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

Now to customize others email notifications (on hold, processing, completed or invoice), you can use any of this filter hooks:

- `woocommerce_email_subject_customer_on_hold_order`
- `woocommerce_email_subject_customer_processing_order`
- `woocommerce_email_subject_customer_completed_order`
- `woocommerce_email_subject_customer_invoice`
- `woocommerce_email_subject_customer_note`
- `woocommerce_email_subject_low_stock`
- `woocommerce_email_subject_no_stock`
- `woocommerce_email_subject_backorder`
- `woocommerce_email_subject_customer_new_account`

---

Addition:

If you want to remove all html to keep the formatted price without html tags, you can replace:

```
wc_price($order->get_total())
```

by *(thanks to **A K**)*:

```
html_entity_decode( strip_tags( wc_price( $order->get_total() ) ) );
```

Comment: 95% of the way there. The variable does appear, but it's surrounded by HTML:

Subject: Order # 123456 - July 11, 2018 - <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span
 class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">&#36;</span>1.00</span>

How do I get rid of the "<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span
 class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">" ?

Comment: @TomJones999 You should click on "reopen" link at the bottom of your question, as your question has everything needed in it and is not off-topic.

Comment: I got this to work by changing one line to this:         html_entity_decode(strip_tags(wc_price($order->get_total()))) // Order Total

Comment: @AK Yes thanks, I have also been using this trick too… I have added that at the end of this thread.