# How customize WooCommerce no stock notification email

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, stock, email-notifications

Kindly am trying to customize the email which is sent automatically from WooCommerce to the admin once a product becomes out of stock. I checked the WooCommerce related setting and it's not in the email tap.

Is there a way to customize the title, body and from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can customize WooCommerce out of stock notification email as follows:

1). Change or add recipient - `woocommerce_email_recipient_no_stock` filter hook:

Code example: [Change stock email notifications recipient in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54904838/change-stock-email-notifications-recipient-in-woocommerce/54906435#54906435)

---

2). Change email subject - `woocommerce_email_subject_no_stock` filter hook:

The original subject code is (located on [`WC_Emails` Class `no_stock()` method](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.5.2/includes/class-wc-emails.php#L641)):

```php
$subject = sprintf( '[%s] %s', $this->get_blogname(), __( 'Product out of stock', 'woocommerce' ) );
```

Code examples: [Customizing email subject with dynamic data in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51214789/customizing-email-subject-with-dynamic-data-in-woocommerce/51218443#51218443)

> You will need to replace `$order` by `$product` and to use `WC_Product` methods instead to avoid errors.

---

3). Change email content - `woocommerce_email_content_no_stock` filter hook:

The original content code is (located on [`WC_Emails` Class `no_stock()` method](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.5.2/includes/class-wc-emails.php#L643)):

```php
$message = sprintf( 
    __( '%s is out of stock.', 'woocommerce' ), 
    html_entity_decode( wp_strip_all_tags( $product->get_formatted_name() ), ENT_QUOTES, get_bloginfo( 'charset' ) ) 
);
```

So you can change it using something like:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_content_no_stock', 'custom_email_content_no_stock', 20, 2 );
function custom_email_content_no_stock( $content, $product ){
    
    return sprintf( 
        __( 'The product "%s" is actually out of stock.', 'woocommerce' ), 
        html_entity_decode( wp_strip_all_tags( $product->get_formatted_name() ), ENT_QUOTES, get_bloginfo( 'charset' ) ) 
    );
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

---

4). Customizing From:

See: [Change sender name and email address for specific WooCommerce email notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46117263/change-sender-name-and-email-address-for-specific-woocommerce-email-notification/46125890#46125890)

**It's not possible to target no stock email notification.**

---

> All available filter hooks are located on [`WC_Emails` Class `no_stock()` method](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.5.2/includes/class-wc-emails.php#L631-L652)…
>
> **Note:** Never use `$this` variable, replace it by `$emails` adding in your code at the beginning:
>
> ```php
> $emails = WC()->mailer;
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```php
> $emails = new WC_Emails();
> ```

Comment: Thank you Loic, but for Part 4 to change the sender name i checked the link but they didn't mention out of stock. do you any idea regarding this ? how i can do it